# do I need to initialize the parent class when inheriting?

Tags: python, super

If I am inheriting from a class and not changing anything in a method, is it required to use super to initialize the method from the parent class?

```
class A:

   def __init__(self):
       self.html = requests.get("example.com").text


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        # is this needed?
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def new_method(self):
        print self.html
```

Comment: You can try it yourself and see. If you don't write a new `__init__` method in `B`, it will still have the one defined in `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you created a `__init__` method in your class `B`, it *overrides* the method in class `A`. If you want it executed, you'll have to use `super()`, yes.

However, if you are not doing anything *else* in `B.__init__`, you may as well just omit it:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.html = requests.get("example.com").text

class B(A):
    def new_method(self):
        print self.html
```

If you want to do anything *in addition* to what `A.__init__()` does, then it makes sense to create a `B.__init__()` method, and from that method, invoke the parent `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not needed to define the overriding method at all.  Python's default behavior is to call the method on the parent class (the next class in the method resolution order) if the current class doesn't override it.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     print("Foo")
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
... 
>>> Bar()
Foo
<__main__.Bar object at 0x7f5ac7d1b990>
```

Notice "Foo" got printed when I initialized a `Bar` instance.

---

If you do define the method, you need to call the super class's method (either explicitly or via super) if you want to make sure that it gets called.